# Testing texts in different languages

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, internationalization, xctest

With Xcode and XCTest I'm trying to test that the currentTitle of a button in a viewControler is "Done" if the language is english, "Hecho" if is spanish, "Fertig" if is deutch and so... but if I change the language in runtime with this code, I have to restart my app:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"es", @"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Is there some way to test the languages in iOS with XCTest?
Thank you for your time.